# Shared memory and performance

Tags: c++, performance, process, shared-memory

What is the performance penalty when accessing a data structure if this is located:

- In the same process memory block.
- In a shared memory block (including locking, but supposing
  no other processes access it for a significant amount of time).

I am interested in an approximate comparison values (e.g. percentage), for access, read and write.

Comment: What makes you think there is _any_? What have you tried benchmarking? On what platform and architecture?

Comment: Well, the locking mechanism, for example. In regard to platform and architecture, the question is generic. I am interested in an approximate value, e.g. 10% vs 90% penalty.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, the question is too broad, please provide the specifics of your question. As for locking, there is always overhead, but again, it depends on the context.

Comment: @Pietro what locking mechanism(s)?  Most memory mapped APIs give you access to the raw pages - any locking/concurrency is up to the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your process memory is `mmap`ed. It does not matter whether one or more processes map the same physical pages of memory, there is no difference in the speed of access in this regard.

What matters in whether memory is located on the local or remote NUMA node.

See NUMA benchmarks in [Challenges of Memory Management on Modern NUMA System](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2852078).

Comment: For now, all memory is local, so no NUMA related slowdowns have to be considered. I am interested in the eventual overhead due to the fact that a memory block is shared among multiple processes, where only one of them is the main block user.

Comment: @Pietro I risk repeating myself: no difference in the speed of access in this regard.